# Compare two images if they have almost identical RGB color distribution

Tags: python, opencv

I have two colored images img1 and img2 as defined below

```
 img1 = cv2.imread("source1")
 img2 = cv2.imread("source2")
```

Now I want to know if the distribution of the RGB value of two images is almost identical.  As a human, I can see from the RGB histogram distribution of the two images that they are almost identical or not. But is there a way that I can do this via OpenCV, that it can tell that two images are almost identical with it comes to its RGB distribution?

```
color = ('b','g','r')
for i,col in enumerate(color):
   histr = cv.calcHist([img1],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
   plt.subplot(1,2,1)
   plt.plot(histr,color = col)
   plt.xlim([0,256])
   plt.title("Img 1")

   histr = cv.calcHist([img2],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
   plt.subplot(1,2,2)
   plt.plot(histr,color = col)
   plt.xlim([0,256])
   plt.title("Img 2")
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can use [`np.allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) to check if all the values of the color channels are within a certain tolerance

Answer (score 1):

If you take each point on the x-axis of the two histograms A and B, then the amount of overlap between the two at that point is the height of the smaller:

```
min(A,B)
```

So, you just need to sum over the points:

```
np.sum(np.minimum(A,B))
```

As an empirical explanation, if both histograms are tall in the same places, the histogram overlap will be high, as will `min(A,B)`. If one is high and one is low, the histogram overlap and `min(A,B)` will be low.

I found a nice illustration [here](https://mpatacchiola.github.io/blog/2016/11/12/the-simplest-classifier-histogram-intersection.html) which usefully also suggests normalisation by dividing by the total number of pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cv2.compareHist() in Python/OpenCV. It takes two histograms that can be 1D, 2D or 3D histograms and returns a metric score of similarity.

See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#gaf4190090efa5c47cb367cf97a9a519bd and https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dc8/tutorial_histogram_comparison.html and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/14/3-ways-compare-histograms-using-opencv-python/, for example